# Constraint layout: Align view below three text view based on maximum height on these three

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: Alignment issu]

Want to align a view below textview depend on height. As in case 1 textview3 height is greater than 1,2 so view is below 2. Same for 2 and 3.

Comment: you don't want to fix height?

Comment: No, As text is dynamic for each textview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with constraint layout beta

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta3'
```

and adding a horizontal barrier.

```
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/constraint_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:text="Hello World \n Constraint Layout Demo \n ABCD"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:text="Hello World "
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:text="Hello World "
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<android.support.constraint.Barrier
    android:id="@+id/barrier_bottom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:barrierDirection="bottom"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="textView2,textView3,textView" />

<View
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/barrier_bottom" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Depending on the text view height the barrier will be at the bottom and you can make sure your view (horizontal line) is below the barrier

Screen shot

[image]

Comment: It is better to use beta version for production

Comment: @RajeshTiwari i believe its stable enough to use it in production. so unless you encounter a major bug don't worry

Comment: Ok will try this and let u know

Comment: @RajeshTiwari did you try?

Comment: Yes its working like the way I needed but it takes too much changes as Constraint layout added extra property Min and Max. Now where width set to 0dp takes wrap_content. :-/

Comment: @RajeshTiwari i din't understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161371/discussion-between-rajesh-tiwari-and-raghunandan).